# Cómo ordenar los ModelAdmin en la administración de Django?

Tags: python, django, ordenamiento, django-admin

Estoy trabajando en django y en la página principal de la administración de django salen los modelos que tengo registrado en mi aplicación, el problema es que salen ordenados alfabéticamente y yo necesito decidir en qué orden van a ser mostrados mis modelos en el menú, hay alguna manera de hacer esto?

Comment: Sobrescribe el método [get_app_list](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c914d6cff176ae6bfab2f33a84bcfd45208f1894/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L533).

Comment: Entiendo, pero me puedes poner un ejemplo, o dejarlo como respuesta a la pregunta